# Python - Tkinter Entry widget problems

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Having a lot of trouble with this bit of code for my project, needing to do a simple multiplication with this code: Error is "Value Error: invalid literal for int() base 10: "

```
    def multcalc():
                        ans1=int(mEntry1.get())  #This is where it's locating the error
                        ans2=int(mEntry2.get()) #
                        print(ans1*ans2) 
                        return
                    multmenu=Tk()
                    mEntry1=StringVar()
                    mEntry2=StringVar()
                    multmenu.geometry('450x450+200+200')
                    multmenu.title('Multiplication')
                    input1msg=Label(text='Enter your first input').pack()
                    input1entry=Entry(multmenu,textvariable=mEntry1).pack()
                    input2msg=Label(text='Enter your second input').pack()
                    input2entry=Entry(multmenu,textvariable=mEntry2).pack() 
                    mCalculate=Button(multmenu,text='Enter',command=multcalc).pack()
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that error because you're trying to make a non-numeric string (`''`) into an integer.  `''` doesn't have an obvious numeric equivalent, so Python can't deal with it. The same would happen if `mEntry.get()` was `'salmon'`.

Is `''` an expected value for `mEntry.get()`?  If so, maybe you need some specific logic to deal with it.  For example, if you want `''` to give you `0`, you could do the following:

```
s = mEntry1.get()
if s != '':
    ans1 = 0
else:
    ans1 = int(s)
```

If `''` isn't an expected value of `mEntry.get()`, then maybe the problem is earlier in your code.